# If a product space is locally compact, then each space is locally compact and all but a finite number of factors are compact

Tags: general-topology, product-space

If $\prod^{\infty}_{i=1} (X_i, T_i)$ is locally compact, then each $(X_i, T_i)$ is locally compact and all but a finite number of $(X_i, T_i)$ are compact.

Let $X=\prod^{\infty}_{i=1} (X_i, T_i)$, then for each $\prod^{\infty}_{i=1} \{x_i\}$ there exists a compact neighborhood $\prod^{\infty}_{i=1} N_{x_i}$ of each $x_i$.  Therefore each $x_i \in N_{x_i}$ where $N_{x_i}$ is a compact subset of $(X_i, T_i)$.

The second part is what is confusing me.  It would seem that $[0,1]^{\Bbb N}$ is countably compact and each $[0,1]$ is compact, so there does not exist a finite number of not compact sets.  Unless by a finite number that's including $0$?

Comment: Yes, zero is totally a finite number in this context. Maybe you could also formulate it this way: At most finitely many $(X_i,T_i)$ are not compact.

Answer (score 5):

The proof is not correct as it stands, because you don't know beforehand that the compact neighbourhood of $x = (x_i)$ is of the form $\prod_i N_{x_i}$.

So you do know that there exists a compact set $C \subseteq \prod_i X_i$ such that $(x_i)$ is in the interior of $C$ (i.e. $C$ is a neighbourhood of $x$).

The latter means that there is a basic open neighbourhood $O = \prod_i O_i$ of $x$, where all $O_i$ are open in $X_i$ and also $F = \{i: O_i \neq X_i \}$ is at most finite, such that $x \in \prod_i O_i \subseteq C$.

This means that for $i \notin F$, we have $O_i = X_i$ and so $X_i = \pi_i[O] \subseteq \pi_i[C] \subseteq X_i$, so $X_i = \pi_i[C]$, and the latter set is compact as $\pi_i$ (a continuous projection) preserves compactness. So for all $i \notin F$ (so for all but finitely many $i$) we have that $X_i$ is compact.

That $X_i$ is locally compact for all $i$ whenever $X = \prod_i X_i$ is follows as all $X_i$ are continuous open images of $X$, and such maps preserve local compactness in general.

Comment: I was nicely reading your proof until.. $ X_i = \pi_i[O] \subseteq \pi_i[C] \subseteq X_i$  more specifically I don't see this part $\pi_i[O] \subseteq \pi_i[C] \subseteq X_i$. Could you explain please?

Comment: @bella $O \subseteq C$ so the same holds for their images under $\pi_i$. $\pi_i$ maps into $X_i$ for the last.

Comment: Oh ok I see $\pi_i[C]\subseteq X_i$ now. Is $O\subseteq C$ because of this $\prod_iO_i\subseteq C$ ?

Comment: @bella indeed. $\prod_i A_i \subseteq \prod_i B_i$ iff for all $i$, $A_i \subseteq B_i$ when all sets involved are non-empty by standard set theory.

Comment: Oh well the notation $O = \prod_i O_i$ changes everything  :) Thank you.

Comment: could you elaborate on why the $X_i$ are locally compact?

Comment: @MyMathYourMath: For $i\notin F$, $X_i=\pi_i(C)$ and hence compact and therefore locally compact. For $i\in F$, note that $x_i\in \pi_i(O)=O_i\subset \pi_i(C)\subset X_i$, whence it follows that $x_i\in X_i$ has a neighborhood contained in a compact subspace of $X_i$. It can be done for any element of $x_i$. This proves the local compactness of $X_i,i\in F$.